# Frequency Images start in the center of table [Homework] [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, html, normalization, frequency

Hi There I have to create a frequency chart for each letter in the word that is added. I have it created but there is a little error you can probably understand from this image:

[image]

Yeah if the letter is not 100px, it starts in the middle for some reason. And I want it to start at the bottom of the td instead of the middle.

So this is the code that creates the table

```
function generateTable(input) {
    var frequency = new Array(26);
    var letters = new Array(26);
    var freqPos = 0;
    var newInput = input.toUpperCase();
    var max = 0;
    var myHeight = 0;
    var test = 9000;
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "orange.gif";
    for (i = 65; i < 91; i++) {
        //looks at how many times each character occurs and stores its value
        frequency[freqPos] = newInput.split(String.fromCharCode(i)).length -
            1;
        freqPos++;
    }
    //checks which letter occured the most
    for (i = 0; i < frequency.length - 1; i++) {
        if (frequency[i] > max) {
            max = frequency[i];
        }
    }

    table = input + "<table border='1'>";
    //first row 
    table += "<tr>";
    table += "<td>Letter Frequency 100px</td>";
    for (i = 0; i < frequency.length; i++) {
        //somehow have to use myHeight to change the height of the image that I make here. 
        myHeight = (frequency[i] / max) * 100;
        myHeight = parseInt(myHeight, 10);
        //document.write(i + ": " + myHeight + "<br \>");
        table += '<td height = "100" width = "8"><img src = "orange.gif" id = "orange" alt = "25" height = "'+myHeight+'" width = "8"></td>';
    }
    table += "</tr>";
    //second row
    table += "<tr>";
    table += "<td></td>";
    for (i = 65; i < 91; i++) {
        table += "<td>" + String.fromCharCode(i) + "</td>";
    }
    table += "</tr>";
    table += "</table>";
    return table;
}
```

Trying to figure out why these start in the middle and how I would align it to the bottom of the cell.

Comment: In future prob best to include fiddle with question like this, as takes a few steps to replicate and is highly contextual so hard to give proven solution without one. Here is your problem in a fiddle I made: https://jsfiddle.net/dabros/vLb1xayx/. Also maybe move away from images and set `background-color` on the element being sized (which could easily be a div inside the td)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can fix that by playing with align.

`<img align="left|right|middle|top|bottom">`.

I'd guess it could work with `<img align="bottom">`

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS:

```
td{
  vertical-align:top; horizontal-align:left; padding:0;
}
```